# elasticsearch randomly not responding to query

Tags: elasticsearch, response

We use elasticsearch since a couple of weeks and there are over 160 million of entries separated in a couple of indexes splitted by month (e.g. index_2014_01,index_2014_02,....).

Sometimes if we send a bulk query requests to the elasticsearch nodes for some requests there is no responses and no timeouts. There is no chance to reproduce this problem because it happens randomly and also on queries which worked seconds before with a minimum response time.
We started to debug down to the elasticsearch transport client without success. We noticed that there was a request without response (Breakpoints were hooked in response-listener, request-listener and failure-listener) - even after a long wait time there was no response or failure. There is no exception or log-output which indicates that problem except that after a time there is a "disconnected from node" message. In the logs from the cluster-nodes there is no error either.
There is not much load on the elasticsearch cluster and on our firewall all ports from 9200 to 9400 are opened.

Our application structure:

> TOMCAT 7 (JAVAEE-7u25) --> spring-data-elasticsearch-1.0.0.M2 -->
>   elasticsearch-1.1.0(1.0.0 with same issue) ----------> elasticsearch
>   (8 nodes) version 1.0.0 (JAVA-7u25)

This issue happens randomly and we have no idea where it comes from.

Has anybody any idea?

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? I'm having the same issue now.

Comment: Yes, the issue has been solved. The config of the firewall was the problem.
It's a known problem. It also appears when several nodes are not in the same network.
The standard tcp keepalive from linux is set to 7200 sec and the firewall is waiting for it after 5000 sec.
So for the firewall the connection is dead, therefore it closes it.
The tcp keepalive must be set lower than the value in the firewall.
This can be done with the following command:
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=4500
Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks so much. Didn't know it might be a problem of firewall. I'll try it.